# Sql Server is removing question marks when insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, dml

I have the following `string (datatype: NVARCHAR(40)): N'?201510292036353?'` that is inserted on a table called: `dbo.LogDetalleSync` (Column `IdLe NVARCHAR(100)`).

The question is simple: 
Why sql server inserts the value without question marks? --> `N'201510292036353'`

It seems to be a problem with some Unicode charactes but I'm not sure.

Hope you can help me.

Regards

Comment: Do you have DB definitions / user defined functions etc., that strip ASCII characters from strings?

Comment: What is the insert statement? Any triggers on the table?

Comment: @user8834780 my table definition is: IdLe: DataType varchar(100), computed: no, nullable: yes, TrimTrailingBlanks: (n/a), FixedLenNullInSource: (n/a), Collation: Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: @JacobH Ther is no triggers

Comment: A shot in the dark, but did you try putting escape character "\" in front of the "?"

Comment: @user8834780 Yeah i tried it but sql is still removing that marks :(

Comment: Works just fine for me

Comment: Works just fine. Please check you have any custom function that removes ? before inserting the record to the tables.

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran yes, i found a function that removes that char from the string. Thank you all for your support

Comment: Sidenote: Seems like you are using varchar to store what appears to be a string representation of a datetime. If that is the case, you should probably store DateTime instead of it's string representation.